# UHF-algebra tracial state is faithful?

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, trace

It is known that a unital UHF-algebra has a unique tracial state, it is true that it is true that this trace is normal and faithful? I am particularly interested in the universal UHF-algebra, i.e. the one with $K_0$ group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$.

I been looking for this in the literature without any success. On the other hand it is clear that if we restrict the trace to any finite factor it is faithful there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The universal UHF algebra has $K_0$-group $\mathbb Q$ and the unique tracial state is faithful because the algebra is simple.

Comment: I just realized that for a trace the left ideal of elements with zero norm trace is also a right ideal. Thanks!

Comment: Also, "normal" is not really defined for the tracial state on the UHF-algebra, but of course the extension to the double dual will be normal.

Comment: When you say double dual, this is equivalent to taking the double commutant of the GNS representation (which in this case is an irreducible faithful representation)?

Comment: Yes exactly, the GNS coming from the unique trace.